# Page Analytics (by Google) does not work fine with russian URLs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have installed Chromium extension Page Analytics (by Google) from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-analytics-by-google/fnbdnhhicmebfgdgglcdacdapkcihcoh?hl=en-US).
And I thought it will help me to look pages statistics: I want to learn what buttons do use people in my site and what do not.

So I have an IDN domain with Russian pages URLs. Page Analytics works fine for main page.

For all the others it shows 0 info - 0 views, 0 clicks and so on.

If I click "View in Google Analytics" it brings me to 0 info page. Google Analytics does not recognize this url: `%b0%d12%0f....`, it uses normal URLs like `нормальный-урл/вот-так`.

How to view my pages statistics?

Comment: This is not a programming question, apparently, but a bug report. You should submit it to Google: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list

Comment: thanks.  i will not cause it need to show reporter e-mail but i do not want. and this question also have programmers question: how to look page statistics: clicks

Comment: Look at it this way: if it's a bug, then until it's fixed _nobody_ can answer your question since data is corrupt. It's a question that's more or less on topic (tools used in programming), but unlikely to get a useful answer. In fact, YOU can probably make the most useful answer by posting a link to the bug report you created (or found) for this issue.